# How to copy an embed in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot fetch a message(embed) and send it to channel where command is invoked.
Following code works fine for normal text message:

```
@bot.command()
async def fetch(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(736984092368830468)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(752779298439430164)
    await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

For sending embeds I tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def fetch(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(736984092368830468)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(752779298439430164)
    await ctx.send(msg.embeds.copy())
```

It sends this instead of sending embed:

[image]

How do I make the bot copy and send embed?

Comment: `msg.embeds.copy()` actually returns an Embed object (you can see it in the module's source code). I have not tried it yet, but seems like `ctx.send()` has a parameter called `embed`. Maybe you should try `await ctx.send(embed=msg.embeds.copy())`

Comment: that doesn't work , gives error - ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'``` @NicholasObert

Comment: Hi @Deadshot if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and therefore how to solve this problem, if they ever came across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the first embed like this and use [copy] if you want to change into it before sending again.(https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.copy)

```py
@bot.command()
async def fetch(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(736984092368830468)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(752779298439430164)
    await ctx.send(embed=msg.embeds[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to send a list of *discord.Embed* objects as a string in your `await ctx.send(msg.embeds.copy())`
The `ctx.send()` method has a parameter called `embed` to send embeds in a message.

```
await ctx.send(embed=msg.embeds[0])
```

Should do the trick. This way you are sending an actual *discord.Embed* object, instead of a list of *discord.Embed*s

You should not need the `.copy()` method in

```
await ctx.send(embed=msg.embeds[0].copy())
```

although you can use it

The only downside of using the index operator `[0]` is that you can only access one embed contained in your message. The discord API does not provide a way to send multiple embeds in a single message. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579638/11811412) question).

A workaround could be iterating over every embed in the `msg.embeds` list and send a message for every embed.

```
for embed in msg.embeds:
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This unfortunately results in multiple messages being sent by the bot, but you don't really notice.