# How to insert multiple embeds in the same command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create several embeds at the same time with a single command but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx, *, habbo):
    urlhabbo = requests.get(f"https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={habbo}")
    placashabbo = urlhabbo.json()
    placas = placashabbo["selectedBadges"]

    contar = 0
    content = ""

    for i in placas:
        contar = contar + 1
        i = i['code']
        content = content + f"\n{i}\n"
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"l", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I need to create several separate embeds with the same command, for example:

https://i.imgur.com/piUQJzf.gif

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send multiple embeds in one message with Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563046/send-multiple-embeds-in-one-message-with-discord-py)

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this `embeds = []`. for example:

```
embeds = [embed, embed2]
await ctx.send(embeds=embeds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
embeds = []
for i in placas:
        contar = contar + 1
        i = i['code']
        content = content + f"\n{i}\n"
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"l", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
        embeds.append(embed)
    
await ctx.send(embeds=embeds)
```

Comment: Hi Chember Bember, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Thanks